# Exercise from Evans' book.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am reading Evans' Partial differential Equations and am stuck with the following problem from chapter 12 on nonlinear wave equation.

Suppose $u$ has a compact support and solves PDE of the form:$$u_{tt}-\sum_{i=1}^n(L_{p_i}(Du))_{x_i}=0.$$ Determine the appropriate energy $E(t)$ and 
show that $(E(t))'=0.$ My first question is: can anybody clarify for me what $L_{p_i}$ stands for here? And what is the form of $L$ then? I was trying to find clarifications in the book but failed. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! We have a bunch of [answered questions from this book](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Evans+%5Bpde%5D) already.

Answer (score 1):

The notation for Lagrangians can be found in the Calculus of Variations chapter. A typical Lagrangian is written as $L(p,z,x)$ where $p\in\mathbb R^n$ stands for the gradient of function ($p=Du(x)$), $z$ for the function itself ($z=u(x)$), and $x$ is the independent variable $x$. Here we have a special case: $L$ is just a function of $Du$.

For example, if $L(p)=|p|^2/2$, then $L_{p_i}(p)=p_i$, hence $L_{p_i}(Du)=u_{x_i}$. Therefore $\sum_i (L_{p_i}(Du))_{x_i} = \Delta u$. 
For this Lagrangian we have the heat equation $u_{tt}-\Delta u$, for which the conserved energy is $\int (u_x^2+u_t^2)\,dx$.

On the basis of this example we can guess that in general $E(t)=\int (2L(Du)+u_t^2)\,dx$. Check if this works: the 
goal is to write $E'(t)$ as an integral of divergence of some field over $\mathbb R^n$. You may want to look at the one-dimensional calculation [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/276979/energy-of-wave-equation-decreasing/277016#277016).

Comment: It does work. Thanks for the clarification and the link to the problems.